A case of interchanging an integral and a series
Let $ \alpha_n $ be a sequence of positive numbers, non-decreasing, with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n = +\infty$. A friend asked me to show:
$$
\int_0^1 \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n x^{\alpha_n} \, dx = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha_n + 1},
$$
by using the Dominated Convergence Theorem , which I recall:

Let $I$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}$. If for almost every $x \in I$, the series $\sum_{n \geq 0} f_n(x)$ converges, and there exists an integrable function $g$ on $I$ such that, $\forall N \geq 1$,
$$
\left| \sum_{n=0}^{N} f_n(x) \right| < g(x) \quad \text{almost everywhere},
$$
then
$$
\sum_{n \geq 0} \int_I f_n \, d\nu = \int_I \sum_{n \geq 0} f_n \, d\nu.
$$

Define $f_n(x) = (-1)^n x^{\alpha_n}$. For fixed $x \in [0,1[$, the alternating series $\sum_{n \geq 0} f_n(x)$ converges by the special criterion for alternating series. Denote by $f$ its simple limit. We even have uniform convergence on $[0, a]$ for any $a \in [0,1[$, because the remainder $R_n(x)$ satisfies:
$$
|R_n(x)| = \left| \sum_{k \geq n+1} f_k(x) \right| \leq |f_{n+1}(x)| = x^{\alpha_{n+1}} \leq a^{\alpha_{n+1}} \to 0.
$$
Thus, $f$ is continuous on $[0,1[$, though not necessarily integrable on $[0,1]$.
However, I am unable to demonstrate the existence of an integrable function $g$ on $I$ such that, $\forall N \geq 1$,
$$
\left| \sum_{n=0}^{N} f_n(x) \right| < g(x) \quad \text{almost everywhere.}
$$

You've already shown $|R_n(x)|$ is bounded above by an integrable function.  A similar argument shows
$$\left|\sum_{n=0}^N(-1)^nx^{\alpha_n}\right| \leq x^{\alpha_0}$$

You're right, simply take $ g(x) = \left| \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n x^{\alpha_n} \right| $. I was blinded. thank you

I think we can avoid using the Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) by noticing that the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly on $[0, a]$ for all $a < 1$. Then, we integrate over $[0, a]$ and take the limit as $a \to 1$.
